# virtualbox (Win 7) network: guest trying to see guest on separate host

Tags: networking, virtualbox

- I have a private network with static addresses on each machine.
- Virtualbox is installed on each machine.
- A virtual Windows 7 is running on each virtualbox.
- Each host can see every other host on the network (independent of Virtualbox, of course).
- By playing with the attachment settings for the virtual network adapter I can get the guest to see itself and the host, on the network.
- I cannot get the guest on one host to see the guest on a separate host.

Firstly, is this possible?
 I have tried the solution recommended here
http://coding4streetcred.com/blog/2012/06/default.aspx
but I may be missing something.
If the feature is not available on virtualbox, is it available via VMware's workstation?
I would obviously prefer to stick with a free solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer to this on the virtualbox forum, The bridged adapter allows for this.
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=56403&p=261118#p261118